# dynamic div positioning one after another and below

Tags: jquery, css

[image: Image, what i want to achieve]
Image, what i want to achieve.

User can create card with content and items. Users also can comment items and card itself. Then what i need, is to display comments like in picture.
Connection lines i made with plumb.js. Div's i can place to right with jQuery

`$('#c' +  comment.id).position({ my: "left top", at: "right top", of: $('#'+comment.parent), collision: "none" });`

In database i store comment parent element ID. For example: "card item 1" ID is i95 (i = item, 95 is auto increment from db).

Problems:

- I cannot determine "user comment on item 2" CSS position.
- If for one item is two or more comments, then how i can place comment after comment? jQuery position() attribute collision doesn't help. (comment are top on each another). (this is biggest problem)
- if comment is commented then i need to place comment on right side.

Cards and comments i get from server witch is three JS objects. (one is cards, one items and comments). First i draw cards, then items and after that comments. In comment object i have card ID, parent ID. In comment object comments not in any order.

one idea is to make list whit arranged comment order. I know in what order is listed items in card. Then i can loop through comment object and detect how many comments is for current card, then look up:

1. card comments
2. card comment comments
3. item no1 comments
4. item no1 comment comments
5. item no2 comments,,,, and so on

then add items to DOM, calculate each comment height and then calculate all positions ..

but maybe there is better way to achieve this...
I don't care IE browsers :)

server side is node.js,

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't either `A)` wrap all the comments into a container, spit them out sequentially from the database, and get this effect, or `B)` use an unordered list. As far as the child comments are concerned, you should have a relationship built into the DB to know whether or not there are child comments. When you spit them back, and if you choose to use `B)`'s method, you could simply append a new unordered list to that LI element and use CSS to tell it where to be positioned. Your method seems fairly overcomplicated and against the grain. 2cp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here. http://jsfiddle.net/63es7/ I cannot add jsplumb connections on jsfiddle. I added collision detection on div's. not a great solution, but i am working on it :)